# How do I add video in Laravel without storing into database

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-6

I've a play-button inside Image. Onclick it shows youtube video in light-box. I just replaced youtube video with my own video from video directory that is under public folder. When i click on play button, it returns below error.

[image]

blade.php

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="col-lg-5 order-2 order-lg-1 align-items-stretch video-box" style='background-image: url({{URL::asset('src/img/product3.png')}})' data-aos="zoom-in">

  <a href="{{URL::asset('src/video/Car-Chain Product 2 ENG.mp4')}}" class="venobox play-btn mb-4" data-vbtype="video" data-autoplay="true"></a>

 </div>
</div>
```

When I changed my anchor tag with video, it open light-box but still video is not playing, just loading..

```
<video src="{{URL::asset('src/video/Car-Chain Product 2 ENG.mp4')}}" class=" play-btn" data-vbtype="video" data-autoplay="true"></video>
```

How can I resolve this please?

Comment: Looks like it's a routing error, not really about loading video assets...

Comment: @Dragonsnap What should I do ?

Comment: Try posting your web routes

Comment: I didn't setup/write any route for this. I simply tried to upload video from my directory under root very similar to image.